# Is it possible to pass an array of values as second argument to _.without() function?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I would like to get a list of all the objects of the first array that are not in the second one (so _.difference() doesn't work in this case). Something like this:

```
_.without([0, 3, 5, 6, 7], [4, 6, 7]); // I would like this to return [0, 3, 5]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you say that `difference` doesn't work? That seems to be exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Check the source. `_.without` calls `_.difference` and returns the result. This question is nonsense. http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-49

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what I did to have this not working ... my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `difference(array,array)` method:

```
 _.difference([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 2, 10]);
 //output=> [1, 3, 4]
```